# WebRTC One to Many Connection

Tags: c++, webrtc, peer

I'm building a personal project that makes a one-to-many connection with other users, this what my plan looks right now:

1. User Initiates a P2P connection with the C++ Server
2. The C++ Server Initiates a P2P Connection with other clients and forwards the stream of the broadcaster

I'm planning to use the WebRTC C++ API available on Google Code Repo. Firstly, is this possible, and secondly is this approach reasonable(and possible) excluding the resource usage factor?

Thanks,

-- Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Firstly, is this possible?"

Yes

"secondly is this approach reasonable?"

Yes

That's exactly what media servers do.